# How to persist the reference of an Item in filtered list in vue2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

So I have a list and I am creating cards on that , it looks like this .

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/gewsu3yd/18/)

```
var vm = new Vue({
  components: {
    'card': card
  },
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    customers: [{
      id: '1',
      name: 'user 1',
      amount: '123.24',
      profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png',
      email: 'ab@gmail.com',
      phone: '+91959657248',
      unread: '0'
    }, {
      id: '2',
      name: 'user 2',
      amount: '34.44',
      profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png',
      email: 'abcd@gmail.com',
      phone: '+919456664023',
      unread: '0'
    }, {
      id: '3',
      name: 'user 3',
      amount: '1.24',
      profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png',
      email: 'test@gmail.com',
      phone: '+919566565065',
      unread: '0'
    }, {
      id: '4',
      name: 'user 4',
      amount: '123.24',
      profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png',
      email: 'sample@gmail.com',
      phone: '+916466004566',
      unread: '0'
    }],
    query: '',
  },
  computed: {
    tableFilter: function() {
      return this.findBy(this.customers, this.query, 'name')
    }
  },
  methods: {
    findBy: function(list, value, column) {
      return list.filter(function(item) {
        return item[column].includes(value)
      })
    },
    updateComission(commission, id) {
      console.log(id);
      alert('I am parent need to update data');
    }
  }
})
```

I want to update the amount in the card when the '+' button is clicked, I was doing previously the index of the list , but every time list is filtered the index is changed and it was updating the wrong data .

Any Idea how I can fix this

Comment: @WannyMiarelli Yes please check the Js Fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the item as prop for the Card component and then to the NumberInputSpinner component.

```
<card v-for="item in tableFilter" :name="item.name" @commission_change="updateComission" :amount="item.amount" :item="item"></card>
    
<numberinputspinner :min="0" :max="2" :step="0.0001" @newNumber="updateTable" :item="item" />
```

then just use the prop to update the list reference

```
increaseNumber() {
  this.numericValue += this.step;
  this.item.amount += this.step;
},
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props

if you want to update the item ref in the card component just emit a update_event form the numberInputSpinner, then update the item reference in the cardComponent

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gewsu3yd/19/